# Linear Algebra- linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u = \pmatrix{-1\\1}$ and $v = \pmatrix{1 \\ 1}$. Express the vectors $\pmatrix{1\\0},\pmatrix{0\\1}$, and $\pmatrix{32\\-15}$ as linear combinations of $u$ and $v$.

Question: Is this 1 problem or three seperate ones? If one then how?

I have tried as three seperate equations and they seem to work. As example:

As first vector $\pmatrix{1\\0}:$
$$
\pmatrix{-1&1&1\\
1&0&1}
$$

Comment: Whoever edited the post thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! For future reference, there's a tutorial on how to format mathematical expressions on this site over [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, if you press the [edit] button for your post, you'll see how I did what I did.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this as 3 separate problems if you'd like, but solving the first 2 will let you solve the third very quickly.

To solve the first, for example: what you're looking for are values $x_1,x_2$ such that
$$
x_1\pmatrix{-1\\1} + x_2 \pmatrix{1\\1} = \pmatrix{1\\0} \implies
\pmatrix{-x_1 + x_2\\x_1 + x_2} = \pmatrix{1\\0}
$$
That is, you're trying to solve the matrix equation
$$
\pmatrix{-1 & 1\\1 & 1} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2} = \pmatrix{1\\0}
$$
You can do something similar for the second.  However, once you have those, there's a quick way to get the third: note that
$$
\pmatrix{32\\-15} = 32 \pmatrix{1\\0} - 15 \pmatrix{0\\1}=\\
32 \pmatrix{-1&1\\1&1}\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2} -
15 \pmatrix{-1&1\\1&1} \pmatrix{y_1\\y_2} = \\
\pmatrix{-1&1\\1&1}\left(
32 \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2} - 15 \pmatrix{y_1\\y_2}
 \right)
$$
So, if $\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2}$ and $\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2}$ are the coefficients that answer the first question, then 
$$
32 \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2} - 15 \pmatrix{y_1\\y_2}
$$
gives you the vector of coefficients answering the third question.

Comment: So it is 3 seperate problems and not 1?

Comment: It doesn't have to be.  In particular, finding the inverse of a matrix is not generally considered "two problems".

Comment: I'm going to add a bit to my post; hopefully that will clear some things up here.

Comment: So its three but all tie togeather. I see.  Thanks a million.

Comment: Note also that $\pmatrix{x_1&y_1\\x_2&y_2}$ is the inverse of $\pmatrix{-1&1\\1&1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that linear combinations by definition means that certain constants will satisfy $a\textbf{v}+b\textbf{u}=\begin{pmatrix}32\\-15\end{pmatrix}$, i.e. they can linearly be added up to produce the sum.

This yields the matrix equation $\begin{pmatrix}{v}_1&{u}_1\\{v}_2&{u}_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}32\\-15\end{pmatrix}$ which you can solve by gaussian elimination or, like in the case, by observation. Recall that some systems may be inconsistent (no solution), have one solution or have infinitely many solutions.